# Aggregation involving two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=["x", "x", "y"], b=[0, 1, 1], c=[1, 2, 2]))
```

I want to aggregate grouping by `a` and doing an aggregation that depends on `b` and `c`. I would want to do something like:

```
df.groupby("a").agg(lambda df: (df["b"] - df["c"]).sum())
```

but this throws the following error in pandas:

```
KeyError: 'b'
```

Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

---

Of course I know I can do something like

```
df.assign(new_b = lambda df: df["b"] - df["c"]).groupby("a").agg({"new_b": 'sum'})
```

which gives the following result:

```
   new_b
a
x     -2
y     -1
```

but there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: Same I obtain using the last command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your operators are commutative, you can do:

```
out = df.groupby('a').sum()
out['new_b'] = out['b'] - out['c']
```

Output:

```
   b  c  new_b
a             
x  1  3     -2
y  1  2     -1
```

**Note**: You're close, this would work

```
df.groupby("a").apply(lambda d: (d["b"] - d["c"]).sum())
```

The difference is that `apply` takes the whole (sub)dataframe as arguments, while `agg` takes each column of the whole (sub)dataframe.